# Is there a way to use full screen apps on Mountain Lion Without Losing 2nd Screen?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, osx-mountain-lion, fullscreen

The Full Screen option in apps on Lion/Mountain Lion is great for maximising screen space unless you run two monitors, at which point the second one just shows a useless texture. Is there a way to get full screen apps on the main monitor and still use the second monitor for displaying other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many users have complained about Apple's Full Screen Apps "functionality" behaving exactly as you've described. I haven't seen anything stating that Apple - which is aware of this - is doing anything about it. I wouldn't hold my breath. Sorry.

This [appleinsider](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/21/inside_os_x_108_mountain_lion_gm_go_full_screen_on_any_display.html) article discusses the issue in more detail and pretty much sums it up as no.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't trying to bust your chops, wasn't sure if you knew the "standard" that most of the questions/answers are tried to be kept to. Looking more I see what you're saying and your answer is spot on. I added a link to appleinsider just to give it a little more credence.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have full screen apps that works with more than 1 display.

Comment: Such a useless feature...

Comment: it is somehow useful for single monitor user, but I am a multiple monitors user.

Comment: The problem is, how hard would it have been to just not blank out the other monitor? Then you would get all that full screen.. usefulness? and still be able to support multi-monitor setups. It's like the change from expose to mission control; you can no longer drag windows from monitor one to monitor two. Apple's multi-monitor and power user support has been going backwards for a while now.